# DataTable to List<Class> without for Loop in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

This is my code part:(with Partial class)

```
   partial class Program
        {
       static DataTable dt;
        Program()
        {
            Initializer();
        }
        class DataItem
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        public void Initializer()
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            //Columns Add
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            //Row of Data Add
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Elango");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Ampa");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Madhu");
        }        
    }
```

Output Method:

```
partial class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pg = new Program();
            DataTable dts = dt;
            List<DataItem> dataItems = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<DataItem> 
         ();
        }
    }
```

Here, I have tried something. If anyone knows how to convert Datatable to List, Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

public partial class Program
        {
       static DataTable dt;
        Program()
        {
            Initializer();
        }
        class DataItem
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        public void Initializer()
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            //Columns Add
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            //Row of Data Add
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Elango");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Ampa");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Madhu");
        }        
    }

public partial class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Program pg = new Program();
            DataTable dts = dt;

            List<DataItem> studentList = new List<DataItem>();  

    studentList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows  
            select new DataItem()  
            {  
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),  
                Name = dr["Name"].ToString()
            }).ToList();  
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the above example not worked to me, Kindly go through my code....

Comment: Edited the code.

Comment: Your statement was correct. but I want without loop concept.